# Syntax with templates in class functions with a binary search tree

Tags: c++, templates

So I am attempting to convert an int based binary search tree I created earlier into a templated binary search tree. I am struggling with how to type out my .cpp file.

In my .h file I have:

```
template <typename T>
class BST
{
private:        
    struct node
    {
        T m_data;
        node* m_left;
        node* m_right;
    };

    node* m_root;
    void AddLeafPrivate(const T& x, node* Ptr);
    void PrintInOrderPrivate(node* Ptr);
    node* ReturnNodePrivate(const T& x, node* Ptr);
    T FindSmallestPrivate(node* Ptr);
    void RemoveNodePrivate(const T& x, node* parent);
    void RemoveRootMatch();
    void RemoveMatch(node* parent, node* match, bool left);
    node* CreateLeaf(const T& x);
    node* ReturnNode(const T& x);
    void RemoveSubtree(node* Ptr);
public:
    BST();
    ~BST();
    void AddLeaf(const T& x);
    void PrintInOrder();
    T ReturnRootKey();
    void PrintChildren(const T& x);
    T FindSmallest();
    void RemoveNode(const T& x);
};
```

In my .cpp file I am getting errors with the following functions:

```
template <typename T>
template BST<T> :: node* BST<T>::ReturnNode(const T& x)
{
  return ReturnNodePrivate(x, m_root);
}

template <typename T>
template BST<T> :: node* BST<T> :: ReturnNodePrivate(const T& x, node* Ptr)
{
if(Ptr != NULL)
{
    if (Ptr -> m_data == x)
    {
        return Ptr;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (x < Ptr -> m_data)
        {
            return ReturnNodePrivate(x, Ptr -> m_left);
        }
        else 
        {
            return ReturnNodePrivate(x, Ptr -> m_right);
        }       
    }
}
else
{
    return NULL;
}
}
```

I am getting the same 4 errors for each function and I am confused what I am doing wrong.

- `error: expected '<' before 'BST' for template BST<T>`
- `error: 'T' was not declared in this scope`
- `error: template argument 1 is invalid`
- `error: expected initializer before '*' token`

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: what are the lines of the errors?

Comment: "In my .cpp file..." in all but the rarest of circumstances you can stop right there. Regarding your error. remove the word `template` before `BST<T>`. It doesn't belong there. Use `typename`.

Comment: @Borgleader No, it doesn't seem to be this problem. The common problems described in the linked question are related to linking not compiling.

Comment: You definitely need to replace the bare `template` on lines 2 and 8 of the cpp with `typename` because `BST<T>::node` is a dependent type.

Comment: @0x499602D2 It's not a duplicate of the linked question...

Comment: Thanks everyone I felt pretty silly after seeing the error. I am now having to deal with some undefined reference errors that I am going to try to solve, I will be back if I cant figure them out. Thanks again for the answers!

Comment: @Justin For that matter, the supposed duplicate has the answer for "undefined reference errors" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you've mistakenly typed `template` twice, instead of `typename`. For example, it should be:

```
template <typename T>
typename BST<T>:: node* BST<T>::ReturnNode(const T& x)
```

instead of:

```
template <typename T>
template BST<T>:: node* BST<T>::ReturnNode(const T& x)
```

Comment: Okay that solved my issue I cant believe I overlooked that thank you!